# Accessibility focus for UI element on Parent Fragment

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm trying to add accessibility support ( Screen reader ) for a screen similar to below

[image]

Button 1 & Button 2 are part of a single fragment and TextView is part of a different child fragment. 
When navigating with the screen reader on the focus moves from 
Button 1 > TextView

When swiping left from TextView the focus doesn't reach Button 2. Instead, the focus is received again by Button 1.

How can I make sure the accessibility focus is correctly received by Button 2.

Layout of parent fragment

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_container"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
            android:text="Button 2" />

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout for child fragment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:importantForAccessibility="yes"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note: If this layout is tested on most devices the focus will come to Button 2 without extra work. But that's not the case in some samsung devices (s8,s9)

I tried the following approach

1. Identify when TextView is in focus in accessibility mode
2. Identify the touch on the screen and identify swipe right
3. Programmatically get focus on Button 2 by firing           `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED`

I was not able to accurately identify the swipe right gesture in accessibility mode.